# Configuracion PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache

Cordial saludo,
He deseado instalar MariaDB, Apache y PhpMyAdmin, logre hacerlo con Apache 2.4 y que funcionara con PHP 8:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando copio PhpMyAdmin 5.2.0 en C:\Apache24\htdocs y trato de ejecutar SETUP no muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que habra que configurar o que hice mal. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Ya has intentado hacer [esto](https://cafedixital.com/blog/instalar-phpmyadmin-en-windows/) o [esto](https://es.wikihow.com/instalar-phpMyAdmin-en-tu-PC)?? Nos comentas luego...

Comment: Nada aun nada, he intentado de todo, y no deseo ni instalar WAMP ni XAMP